# Simplify a BASH scripting design

Tags: linux, bash

I have need to execute a command in a script an arbitrary number of times with associated arbitrary parameters.

I've decided the script will take its cue from a parameter file (`parameter.txt`) where lines are of the form:

```
label param1 param2
```

For each line in `parameter.txt`, I'll call the command with the specified parameters.

So far, my tinkering is moving along the lines of the following, but it's looking messy:

```
while read line; do 
    echo $line | sed -r 's/[^ ]+ ([^ ]+).+/\1/' && 
        echo $line | sed -r 's/[^ ]+ [^ ]+ ([^ ]+)/\1/'
done < parameter.txt
```

My command is of the form:

```
mycmd -a param1 -b param2 > label
```

**Could I get some suggestions how I might simplify this?**

*I'm doing this for a small embedded system whose 'helper' commands are in short supply (`xargs` for example isn't available, and things like `awk` are hobbled busybox implementations), and I'm using version 2 (2.04g I think) of BASH.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while read label param1 param2; do
    mycmd -a "$param1" -b "$param2" > "$label"
done < parameter.txt
```

Comment: Love it.  Full points for brevity and making me feel sheepish for not RFM'ing the `read` man page.

Comment: If you want to ignore after param3, use `read label param1 param2 ignored` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a function, as long as there aren't any embedded spaces.

```
function x()
{
    mycmd -a $2 -b $3 >$1
}

while read line; do x $line ; done <parameter.txt
```

Comment: Nice.  I hadn't thought of parameterizing the line with a function call, will add that to my bag of tricks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while read line ; do
    set -- $line
    dest="$1"
    shift

    mycmd "$@" > "$dest"
done < parameter.txt
```

should work. If the parameters in the file have spaces, you will have to quote them properly.

I suggest to add the `-a`, `-b` to the file `parameter.txt` because generating them on the fly is probably brittle.

If you don't like this solution, then I suggest to create a new script from this one which contains the actual commands. That way, you can easily debug any problems.

When the script looks okay, you can source it with `source ./generated.sh` (yes, you have to specify the path).